# Using no aggregate function to get the top 5 for each customer

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I would like to get the top 5 quantity for every customers from this table. I am able to get it through rank and row number, but I think there is a way using no aggregate function to achieve this.

DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE pd_orders (
  `ordered_date` DATETIME,
  `order_code` VARCHAR(15),
  `customer_code` VARCHAR(14),
  `product_name` VARCHAR(10),
  `quantity` INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO pd_orders
  (`ordered_date`, `order_code`, `customer_code`, `product_name`, `quantity`)
VALUES
  ('2023/1/17', '662370230_FP_TW', '1676797_FP_TW', 'product_1', '10'),
  ('2023/1/17', '662370230_FP_TW', '1676797_FP_TW', 'product_2', '10'),
  ('2023/1/17', '662102654_FP_TW', '3794354_FP_TW', 'product_3', '8'),
  ('2023/1/17', '662513860_FP_TW', '3989950_FP_TW', 'product_4', '8'),
  ('2023/1/17', '662070842_FP_TW', '2384070_FP_TW', 'product_5', '5'),
  ('2023/1/17', '662097031_FP_TW', '8080834_FP_TW', 'product_6', '4'),
  ('2023/1/17', '662097031_FP_TW', '8080834_FP_TW', 'product_7', '4'),
  ('2023/1/17', '662025835_FP_TW', '1635359_FP_TW', 'product_8', '6'),
  ('2023/1/17', '662025835_FP_TW', '1635359_FP_TW', 'product_9', '4'),
  ('2023/1/17', '662025835_FP_TW', '1635359_FP_TW', 'product_10', '4'),
  ('2023/1/17', '662025835_FP_TW', '1635359_FP_TW', 'product_11', '4'),
  ('2023/1/17', '662177606_FP_TW', '4400774_FP_TW', 'product_12', '5'),
  ('2023/1/17', '662177606_FP_TW', '4400774_FP_TW', 'product_13', '5'),
  ('2023/1/17', '662177606_FP_TW', '4400774_FP_TW', 'product_14', '5'),
  ('2023/1/17', '662333911_FP_TW', '6798862_FP_TW', 'product_15', '4'),
  ('2023/1/17', '662333911_FP_TW', '6798862_FP_TW', 'product_16', '7'),
  ('2023/1/17', '662376770_FP_TW', '717440_FP_TW', 'product_17', '4'),
  ('2023/1/17', '662376770_FP_TW', '717440_FP_TW', 'product_18', '4'),
  ('2023/1/17', '662260058_FP_TW', '10822485_FP_TW', 'product_19', '4'),
  ('2023/1/17', '662260058_FP_TW', '10822485_FP_TW', 'product_20', '6'),
  ('2023/1/17', '662260058_FP_TW', '10822485_FP_TW', 'product_21', '5'),
  ('2023/1/17', '662201603_FP_TW', '2653694_FP_TW', 'product_22', '6');
```

Solution using Rank()

```
SELECT
  customer_code,
  product_name,
  quantity,
  RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY quantity DESC, product_name) AS product_rank
FROM
  pd_orders
WHERE
  MONTH(ordered_date) = 1
```

Solution 1:

```
SELECT
  customer_code,
  product_name,
  quantity,
  RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY quantity DESC, product_name) AS product_rank
FROM
  pd_orders
WHERE
  MONTH(ordered_date) = 1
```

Solution 2:

```
SELECT
  customer_code,
  product_name,
  quantity,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY quantity DESC, product_name) AS product_rank
FROM
  pd_orders
WHERE
  MONTH(ordered_date) = 1
```

Solution 3:

I kind of having idea that we can create the rank column by let the table's quantity compares with itself but no idea how to do it, below is code i tried but failed

```
select p1.customer_code,
p1.quantity, 
count(p2.quantity) Sales_Rank

from pd_orders p1, pd_orders p2
where p2.quantity <= p1.quantity

group by p1.customer_code, p1.quantity
order by p1.quantity desc
```

Comment: FWIW, `rank` isn't an aggregate function, it's a window function. Regardless, if the query with `rank` gets you the right result, why would you not want to use it?

Comment: If it works why change it?  Unless performance is super bad, but even then you should be able to fix that with indexes.  I think what you have is best approach.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite clear about the reason why you don't want to use aggregate/window functions. But if you are using MySQL version 8.0, there is a way that could achieve your result without using these functions. We sort the data by `customer_code, quantity DESC` and using a SQL variable to calculate order rank per each customer. Then with that ranked data, you could apply filter on order rank to retrieve the result that you want to get.

```
SELECT 
   customer_code, product_name, quantity, order_rank   
FROM 
  (SELECT
    customer_code, product_name, quantity,
    @rank := IF(@current_customer = customer_code, @rank + 1, 1) AS order_rank,
    @current_customer := customer_code 
  FROM
    pd_orders
  WHERE
    MONTH(ordered_date) = 1  
  ORDER BY customer_code, quantity DESC) ranked_data
WHERE order_rank <= 5;
```

You could see demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/4h0iZymh).